# Implementing Discussion forum in SDL tridion

Tags: architecture

We are implementing a website using SDL Tridion. We need to develop/integrate "Discussion Forum" functionality in this website.

This website is built in .Net and using SSO for authentication.

Please suggest.

Comment: Voting to close. As currently written this question is to broad. If as Chris suggested you can re-write this question to be more focused please do so and we can vote to reopen this question.

Answer (score 8):

Without specifying what level of integration you need, this is rather hard to answer. However the best answer I can give you (which almost all of the times works) is starting with a question:

> How would you solve this without SDL Tridion?

You will most likely do it with SDL Tridion the exact same way as you would do it without. Only if you have a need for moderation tools inside the CME interface, then you are looking towards a real integration scenario, otherwise I would just call it adding functionality to your website, rather than an integration with SDL Tridion.

*ps. please also note the [FAQ](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) for this site, your question should be  practical and answerable. Your last statement being "Please suggest", actually makes it more an open-ended question which diminishes the usefulness of this site.*

Answer (score 2):

I would strongly suggest not developing this within Tridion, but choose a .NET based Discussion Forum Tool that you want to integrate with. As Bart suggests, figure out how  you want to integrate with it without Tridion first.

Assuming you have some kind of high level ASP.NET application architecture (Using MVC, ASPX or something else). Select a tool that you can easily integrate on the front end first.

Then think about what you need in terms with regard to integrating with Tridion. Do you really need to "integrate" features like users, and linking them to Audience Manager etc? or do you just need to be able to place .NET based engine components on a page which has it's look and feel managed in the same way as your Tridion managed pages?

Once you have that figured out, please write a more focused question if you need more help.